# Making a simple timetable work using an array and nested loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, nested

I have this problem I want to make a timestable output to the console.log, but having problems with the array as am I beginner. Here is my code, been staring a while at this. Sincerely.

```
<script>

// Simple array to store and output times’ tables 
var timesTable = new Array(12); 
var multiplier =6;
timesTable[0] = 0 * multiplier; 
timesTable[1] = 1 * multiplier; 
timesTable[2] = 2 * multiplier; 
timesTable[3] = 3 * multiplier; 
timesTable[4] = 4 * multiplier; 
timesTable[5] = 5 * multiplier; 
timesTable[5] = 5 * multiplier; 


    for (multiplier=0; multiplier<13; multiplier++){

        console.log("0 x " + multiplier +  " = " + timesTable[12])


for (timesTable=0; timesTable<12; timesTable++){

}} 
</script>
```

Comment: can you give an example of the output you expect?

Comment: 6 x 1= 6 and going up, while building on top  of each other

Comment: You will loose the `timesTable` array in the second `for`, since you're setting `timesTable = 0`.

Comment: oh ok, @Teemu the aim is to make a 6 x timestable up to 12 using loops and array

Answer (score 0):

```
// create an array
var a = [];
var multi = 6;

// fill array with values
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) { a.push(i); }

// multiply every array-element with 6 and create new array
var b = a.map(function (j) { return j * multi; })

// log
for (i = 0; i < b.length; i += 1) {
  console.log(i + ' x ' + multi + ' = ' + b[i]);
  // or:
  // console.log(a[i] + ' x ' + multi + ' = ' + b[i]);
}
```